# Will an 85W power adapter fry the MBP 13" Mid 2009?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, power, hardware-recommendation, magsafe

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700), the 60W version of Magsafe is compatible with the MBP 13" Mid 2009. However, I've read that the 85W version is also compatible and leads to faster charge times. I'll keep this short and say, is that correct? Or will it fry my Mac?

P.S - I also read that the 'T style' and 'L style' cords are interchangeable. Could someone please second that?

Thanks

Comment: No it won't. The mac will only draw what it needs. They are interchangeable.

Comment: @1110101001 Have you tried it?  The voltages on the 65W and on the 85W are different...

Comment: @Alex yes, see response to the comment in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can charge any MacBook with a MagSafe 1 charging port with any MagSafe 1 charger.

If the charger has a higher wattage than the one that shipped with your MacBook you can use it safely.

Your MacBook may charge faster with a charger that has a higher wattage, but it won't overcharge. The MacBook's power controller handles this on its own.

---

Charger-styles

Yes, you can use a T-shaped MagSafe 1 charger as well as an L-shaped MagSafe 1 charger with any MagSafe 1 compatible MacBook.

Comment: Have you tried it? The voltages on the 65W and on the 85W are different, so theoretically, frying the computer is entirely possible.

Comment: usb-c power delivery has voltage negotiation. Older magsafe has its own voltage negotiation as you can read in https://www.righto.com/2015/11/macbook-charger-teardown-surprising.html

Comment: Can also see comments in https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/replacing-apple-magsafe-85w-charger-with-a-normal-laptop-psu-possible/ 

>The 85w Magsafe has dual voltages with 16.5v at lower power mode and 18.5v at high power mode. They do this to put less strain on the internal components of the MacBook Pro

Btw supposedly even driving it off 20V DC should be fine, I've read some people do that: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/apple-magsafe-power-brick/

Comment: @1110101001 Wow, thanks, this is real interesting information; I wish I could up-vote something to thank you for these links...